# Ошибка android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    public void formatOut(RelativeLayout nameLMass[]){
    int max = 0;
    for(TextView tv : NameIdEllements){
        tv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        if(tv.getMeasuredHeight() > max) max = tv.getHeight();
    }

    for(RelativeLayout rl : nameLMass){
        int h = rl.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rl.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = h + max - 25;
        rl.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Выкидывает на строке

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rl.getLayoutParams();
```

> можете показать xml layout где у вас RelativeLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bacground_main">
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center">
     <!-- Первая пара -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one"
                android:minHeight="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_one_para"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_one_top"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_one_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_one_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- Вторая пара -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTwo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_two_top"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_two_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_two_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_two_top"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
         <!-- Третья пара -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutThree"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_three"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_two_three"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewThree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_two_three"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_three_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_three_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Четвертая пара -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutFour"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_four"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_four_three"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_four_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_four_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFour"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_four_three"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Пятая пара -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutFive"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_five"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_five_three"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_five_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_five_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewFive"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_five_three"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Шестая пара -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSix"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_six"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_six_three"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_six_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_six_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSix"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view_six"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_six_three"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Седьмая пара -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSeven"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_seven"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_two_seven"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_seven_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_seven_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSeven"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_two_seven"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

> Как и из чего вы получаете переменную rl?

```
    nameLayout[0] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutOne);
    nameLayout[1] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTwo);
    nameLayout[2] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutThree);
    nameLayout[3] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutFour);
    nameLayout[4] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutFive);
    nameLayout[5] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSix);
    nameLayout[6] = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSeven);
```

Comment: можете показать xml layout где у вас RelativeLayout?

Comment: оно пишет что вы пытаетесь сделать из `LinearLayout` `RelativeLayout`, а он против такого насилия. Как и из чего вы получаете переменную `rl`?

Comment: Дело в том, что `LayoutParams` относится к родительскому контейнеру, который у вас `LinearLayout`, а не к тому, который вы обрабатываете. То есть, это параметры родительского виджета. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599706/7566397)

Comment: Но там создаются новые виджеты, а мне нужно изменить размер